# Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (tx)(1-\cos x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $0<t<\pi$

Tags: integration

**Problem :**

Show that 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (tx)(1-\cos x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Where $0<t<\pi$.

---

At first, I set new parameter $t$.
$$f(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (tx)(1-\cos x)}{x}dx$$
and
$$f'(t)=\int_0^\infty \cos (tx)(1-\cos x)dx$$
But this doesn't make any sense.

So I need other approach but I don't have any idea. Thanks for help.

Comment: First do a variable change $y = tx$ and then try the same sort of argument.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(tx)(1 - \cos(x)) = [2 \sin(t x) + \sin((1-t)x) - \sin((1+t)x)]/2$.

Comment: Are you sure the condition on $t$ shouldn't read $0<t<1$? As stated, the assertion fails when $t>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not always possible to take the derivative inside the integral. Take the similar example:

$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(tx)}x~\mathrm dx$$

The derivative cannot be taken like so:

$$I'(t)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(tx)}x~\mathrm dx\ne\int_0^\infty\frac\partial{\partial t}\frac{\sin(tx)}x~\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\cos(tx)~\mathrm dx$$

Instead, by substituting $u=tx$, as [suggested by Zarrax](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320301/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac-sin-tx1-cos-xxdx-frac-pi2-where#comment6831487_3320301), we get for $t>0$

$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}u~\mathrm du$$

and for $t<0$, we have by symmetry

$$I(t)=-\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}u~\mathrm du$$

which is clearly constant over each respective interval. At $t=0$, the integral is trivially zero. Combine this with [John Barber's hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320301/prove-that-int-0-infty-frac-sin-tx1-cos-xxdx-frac-pi2-where#comment6831499_3320301):

$$\sin(tx)(1-\cos(x))=\frac{2\sin(tx)+\sin[(1-t)x]-\sin[(1+t)x]}2$$

and you should be able to see the result. Take note that $I(1-t)$ passes through three different values on $(0,\pi)$, so the integral is not actually constant on the entire interval.

Comment: Wait, something's a bit off. I think the original statement should read $0 < t < 1$ instead of $0 < t < \pi$, otherwise you get in trouble with the $(1-t)$ term.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you use John Barber's hint and assuming that you know the sine integral function, you should get
$$\int \frac{\sin (tx)(1-\cos (x))}{x}\,dx=\text{Si}(t x)-\frac{1}{2} \text{Si}((t+1) x)-\frac{1}{2} \text{Si}((t-1) x)$$ which, formally, make
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (tx)(1-\cos x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}   (\text{sgn}(1-t)+2 \text{sgn}(t)-\text{sgn}(1+t))$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know that

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin ax}{x} dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a>0) \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a<0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This can be derived by the following integration.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&I=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\alpha x}\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx\,\,\,\,\,(\alpha>0)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now take the derivative by $a$ of the above integral.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{dI}{da}=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\alpha x}\cos ax\,dx=\frac{\alpha}
{\alpha^2+a^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This means that,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
I=\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{\alpha}+const.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Since when $a=0$, $I=0$, therefore const. above should be $0$. So, by taking limit$\,(\alpha\rightarrow0$)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&I=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\alpha x}\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx
=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin ax}{x}dx
=\left[\tan^{-1}\frac{a}{\alpha}\right]^{\infty}_0 \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a>0) \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\, (a<0) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Of course the integral is zero when $a=0$.

Now, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin tx(1-\cos x)}{x}=\frac{\sin tx}{x}
-\frac{1}{2}
\left[
\frac{\sin (t+1)x}{x}+\frac{\sin (t-1)x}{x}
\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Therefore, the integral in question can be solved as,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin tx(1-\cos x)}{x}dx \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}
-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,\,\,(t<1) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}
-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
=0\,\,\,\,\,(t>1) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}
-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
=\frac{\pi}{4}\,\,\,\,\,(t=1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(t)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t x)(1-\cos x)}{x} d x \\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t x)}{tx} d (tx)}_{=\frac{\pi}{2}}-\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t x) \cos x}{x} d x}_{J(t)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating $J(t)$ w.r.t. $t$ yields
$$
J^{\prime}(t)=\int_0^{\infty} \cos (t x) \cos x d x=0 \Rightarrow J(t)=J(0)=0
$$
We now conclude that
$$I(t)=\frac \pi 2 $$